# Ejecutar comandos de go que son enviados mediante formulario HTML

Tags: go

Estoy intentando devolver el resultado de una ejecucion de un codigo
escrito en Go.

La idea es enviar algo como esto desde un `textarea`:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hola")
}
```

Y que la api regrese "Hola", como lo hacen en Go playground.

Este es mi codigo:

```golang
func executeCommand() (string, error) {
code := `
    package main

    import "fmt"

    func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hola")
    }`

    cmd := exec.Command("go", "run")

    cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(code)

    output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(output), nil
}
```

Pero no funciona me dice exit(1), alguien me puede dar una pista?

Estoy pasando `cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader(code)` "hardcodeado" pero tampoco logro
devolver lo esperado.

Comment: Hola Nahuel. Una pregunta. Qué tiene que ver el HTML del encabezado de tu pregunta con el código que pusiste?
Podrías poner un ejemplo de lo quisieras tener y qué quieres obtener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que se tiene es que no se está pasando ningún nombre de archivo al comando `go`; lo que se está haciendo:

```golang
exec.Command("go", "run")
```

se debe cambiar por:

```golang
exec.Command("go", "run", "nombre_de_tu_archivo_generado.go")
```

Ahora supongo que se uno se preguntará *¿qué se supone que escriba en el nombre del archivo generado?*

Lo que se debe hacer es copiar el contenido de la variable que el usuario ingresa (puede ser tipo `string` o `[]byte` o interfaz `io.Reader`, que en este caso vendría siendo la variable *code* que está harcodeada y que es de tipo `string`) y escribirla a un archivo en el sistema local con una serie de funciones:

- `filepath.Abs(path string)` Esta función permitirá definir una ruta relativa o absoluta donde se guardará el archivo de entrada del usuario

```golang
fileUrl, err := filepath.Abs("./nombre_de_archivo.go")
```

- `os.Create(fileUrl string)` Esta función creará un archivo vacío en el sistema en la ruta dada como parámetro

```golang
file, err := os.Create(fileUrl)
```

- `io.Copy(destino io.Writer, fuente io.Reader)` Esta función copiará en el *destino* todo el contenido que este en la variable *fuente*

```golang
_, err := io.Copy(file, codeReader) // debe convertir su variable "code" a tipo io.Reader con la ayuda de otra funcion, ya esto depende del tipo de dato, revise strings.NewReader(s string) y bytes.NewReader(b []byte)
```

Ya sería todo. Ahora a ejecutar la función:

```golang
output, err := exec.Command("go", "run", fileUrl).Output()
```

Ya tendría acceso a la salida de lo que haya programado el usuario en la variable `output`.

##### Código final:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    /* conexion por http o algo por el estilo para
       obtener el programa del usuario */
    userProgram := `package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hola mundo")
}`
    if err := runGoProgram([]byte(userProgram)); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func runGoProgram(program []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    // main.go file creation
    programFileUrl, err := filepath.Abs("./user-program/main.go")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    programFile, err := os.Create(programFileUrl)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    if _, err := io.Copy(file, bytes.NewReader(program)); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // go.mod file creation
    goModUrl, err := filepath.Abs("./user-program/go.mod")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    goModFile, err := os.Create(goModUrl)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer file.Close()
    goModContent := `module user-program

go 1.19`
    _, err := io.Copy(goModFile, strings.NewReader(goModContent))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return exec.Command("go", "run" "./user-program/main.go").Output()
}
```